# Delphi 7 Buffer Pointer Overlay Has Different Data

Tags: delphi, pointers, overlay

I define a large buffer and pointer as an Array of Byte in Delphi 7.
This is the buffer for the Win32 ReadEventLog call.

I define a second pointer as a record structure for the buffer data.
This is an overlay to add structure to an array of bytes.

Problem:  data at the two pointers is different.
Buffer^ data is not the same as RecordPtr^ data.
The addresses of both pointers are the same.

Question: what is the correct method of declaring an overlay pointer?

```
Type
  TEventRecord = record
    Length       : dword;
    Reserved     : dword;
    RecordNumber : dword;
    end;

  TByteArray = array of byte;

Var
  Buffer : TByteArray;
  RecordPtr : ^TEventRecord = @Buffer;
  MyData : TEventRecord;

begin
  Setlength (Buffer, $FFF0);
  // ReadEventLog....
  // Watch of Buffer^ and RecordPtr^ shows different data
end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic array `Buffer: array of byte` is a pointer, so `@Buffer` is pointer to pointer.

To make per-byte access to the contents of `TEventRecord`, you can assign pointer to the beginning of byte array data:

```
type
  PEventRecord = ^TEventRecord;

var
  PEventRecord_Var: PEventRecord;

begin
  PEventRecord_Var := @Buffer[0];
```

Comment: This is the solution that works in the live code.

I was initializing the PEventRecord_Var as part of the Type section.  Legal, but does not work correctly.

I moved the assignment out of Type and under Begin, and it now works correctly.  

Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u do it like this?

```
Type
  TEventRecord = record
    Length       : dword;
    Reserved     : dword;
    RecordNumber : dword;
    end;

  TEventLog = array of TEventRecord ;

Var
  Buffer : TEventLog;

begin
  Setlength (Buffer, $FFF0);
  // ReadEventLog(@buffer[0],...) 

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
type
  TEventRecord = record
    Length: DWORD;
    Reserved: DWORD;
    RecordNumber: DWORD;
  end;

  TByteArray = array of Byte;

Var
  Buffer: TByteArray;
  RecordPtr: ^TEventRecord = Pointer(Buffer); // Buffer is a pointer
  MyData: TEventRecord;

begin
  SetLength(Buffer, $FFF0); { Assuming that is big enough }
  { ReadEventLog(..., Pointer(Buffer), Length(Buffer), .... }
  { Watch of Buffer and RecordPtr^ shows same data. }
end.
```

Buffer is a pointer, and it points to the first of a (big) number of bytes. If you want to use this buffer to let ReadEventLog load into a byte array, simply cast Buffer to a Pointer and assign it to RecordPtr.

#### But...

if I understand you well, an alternative is:

```
Buffer: array of TEventRecord;
...
SetLength(Buffer, 6000); { 6000 event records! }
if ReadEventLog(..., Pointer(Buffer), Length(Buffer) * SizeOf(Buffer[0]), ...) then ...
```

Now you can easily access each event record from the Buffer. Why use a Byte array, if, instead, you can easily read an array of event records directly?

*(The above would work for normal records, but I was told by @BruceGavin that event records have a variable size tail, so that won't work)*

Comment: Event Log records have a variant part.  The length of each record varies by the content.  Some are 136 bytes long, others are a couple hundred bytes or more, depending upon the text content, source, user SID, etc.

My record example above was simplified for clarity.

Comment: @Bruce: Ah, OK, then he byte approach is the only one.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve what you are looking for like this :

```
Var
  Buffer : TByteArray;
  RecordPtr : ^TEventRecord absolute Buffer;
```

This make both variable occupy the same 4 bytes in memory (or 8 bytes in 64 bits).